# Oracle SQL - Selecting a value from select and using it as part of the insert

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, insert

I'm selecting a number value and storing it into a variable, but when I use it in the insert statement, I'm getting this error:

> ORA-00984: column not allowed here.

This is my SQL:

```
DECLARE
   RyanuserID NUMBER(10);
BEGIN
   SELECT Publisher_ID
   INTO RyanuserID
   FROM tblPublishers
   WHERE Publisher_Name ='Ryan'
   AND ROWNUM = 1;
END;
/

INSERT INTO tblBooks (Barcode, Book_Title, Publisher_ID, Year_Published, Stock) 
VALUES ('45879654236547', 'Lean HTML and CSS', RyanuserID, '2010', 4);
```

Any suggestions please? Many thanks

Comment: You should be worried by the `rownum = 1`. If that's necessary, because `publisher_name` is not unique then `publisher_id` is essentially random, which is odd for something which seems like it ought to be a foreign key.

Comment: Publisher name is unique, I just put that in as safety, but I guess I should remove it if its not needed. Thanks you for the pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could phrase this as a single insert statement using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO tblBooks (Barcode, Book_Title, Publisher_ID, Year_Published, Stock)
SELECT '45879654236547', 'Lean HTML and CSS', Publisher_ID, '2010', 4
FROM tblPublishers
WHERE Publisher_Name = 'Ryan' AND ROWNUM = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should take it between `begin` .. `end` statements. Because `RyanuserID` is not recognised in this way, and It's better to define as type of returning column from the point of view of compatibility with table's column type and variable's type(`tblPublishers.Publisher_ID%type`).

```
DECLARE 
   RyanuserID tblPublishers.Publisher_ID%type := &i_pbl_id; -- as an initialization value you may call in such a way.
   v_publisher_name tblPublishers.Publisher_Name%type := '&i_pbl_name' -- Ryan (as one of values);
BEGIN
   SELECT Publisher_ID  INTO RyanuserID FROM tblPublishers WHERE Publisher_Name = v_publisher_name AND ROWNUM = 1;
   INSERT INTO tblBooks (Barcode, Book_Title, Publisher_ID, Year_Published, Stock) VALUES ('45879654236547', 'Lean HTML and CSS', RyanuserID, '2010', 4);
END;
/
```

> Moreover, it's always better to use `bind variables` instead of
>   `literals` as above samples. Since, `literals` mean parsing a SQL
>   evertime.